# Constraint satisfied but returns UNSAT Z3

Tags: z3

Here is my problem. I have way too many constraints. Hence the unsat core generated is not informative. However, I manually started excluding constraints and I zeroed down on a set of problematic constraints. My aim is to check for perhaps known issues with Z3. I am calculating probabilities with real variables `p`. I impose bounds on them

```
p1<= 1.0
p1>= 0.0
p2<= 1.0
p2>= 0.0
```

There is a constraint that calculates probabilities.

```
a=1 and b=0 implies p1 = c * p2
```

`c` here is a constant. `a` , `b` are real variables.

Now, what I observe is, I get an UNSAT but having removed the bounds, I get a SAT. The strange thing though when I traverse through the model, the assignments made to p1 and p2 are between 0 and 1. To be precise 1 hence not violating these bounds. Is there any known issue similar to this? I understand this is too vague but I am not sure how to present this question without putting my whole project here...

Comment: So should we understand that your constraints 
involve non-linear polynomials over the reals?
In that case, there is a question whether you use the dedicated non-linear solver or the more general solver (Z3 could use different backends depending on how problems are presented). Can you check if the alledged model is really a model of the formula.

Comment: sorry, it is linear over reals. `c` is a constant.

Comment: I just checked with `Z3_model_to_string` function and I get the exact fractions that have been assigned to variables. Turns out there are an awful lot of digits. One of the assignments for example, is `214182245414561645441490496614564/214182245414561641838610794718167`
Which turns out is when calculated beyond a few decimal places is `1.000000000000000016821560979169039255272413681161082369357703...`

Comment: I am not sure where this precision is lost. The functions used to retrieve this information is `Z3_ast_to_string` and `mpq_set_str(tmp, Z3_ast_to_string(z3, val_ast), 50)`. I was using `double` but now changed it to `long double` but the precision is still lost somewhere!

Comment: Some comments. 1) Z3 represents rational numbers using arbitrary precision arithmetic. So, precision is not an issue. 2) We should not check the Z3 solution using `long double` (due to rounding in floating point computations). 3) Z3 can evaluate expressions in the produced model/solution. 4) If you provide the actual problem/formula you sent to Z3, we will be able to provide better feedback.